# Why react is not rendering updated states?

Tags: reactjs

I am updating data even before initializing the state to that data, but react is rendering the old data.

```
class NewOrders extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            NewOrders:[],
        }
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        this.getNewOrders();
      }
      
    getNewOrders = async () => {
        let data = await api.get(`SellerOrdersAPI/${store.getState().auth.user.id}/`).then(({data})=>data);
        data.map(a =>
            this.get(a)
            )
        console.log(this.state.NewOrders) 
        this.setState({NewOrders:data}) 
    }
    get = async(a) => {
        let data1 = await itemApi.get(`/${a.item}/`).then(({data})=>data);
        let data2 = await userApi.get(`/${a.buyer}/`).then(({data})=>data);
        a.item = data1.title
        a.buyer = data2[0].first_name+' '+data2[0].last_name
    }
render() {
    return(
      -----
)}}
```

Now react is rendering the state displays old data but in **console.log** it's displaying updated data?

how to get this updated data at first?

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3OMk.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

You are mutating the state directly by setting some properties on objects that are in your state in `get()`. React state should never be mutated:

```
// this mutates a which is an object already in your state
a.item = data1.title
```

As `get()` is async this will happen **after** you've already set `data` in `getNewOrders()`. React is not aware of those updates. You need to call `this.setState` again whenever you change anything inside of the state object. Also you should always create new objects instead of mutating objects in the state object.